# Python 3 incorrect output of UTF-8 characters received over WebSocket?

Tags: javascript, python, windows, utf-8, websocket

I have a javascript that sends unicode star character.

But python interprets it as letter **â** -  both in console and in log file.

Other unicode characters are malformed as well.

```
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8888/");

    ws.onopen= function(){
        console.log('\u2605');

        ws.send('\u2605');

        ws.close();
    }
```

Code in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import logging, json
from websocket_server import WebsocketServer   

def new_client(client, server):
    print("Client id:"+ str(client["id"])+ " has connected")

def client_left(client, server):
    print("Client id:"+ str(client["id"])+ " has diconnected")

logfile= open('C:/host/test-log.log', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
logging.basicConfig(stream=logfile,
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(message)s')     

def msg_rcvd(client, server, msg):
    print (msg);
    logging.info(msg);

server = WebsocketServer(8888, host='127.0.0.1')
server.set_fn_new_client(new_client)
server.set_fn_message_received(msg_rcvd)
server.set_fn_client_left(client_left)

server.run_forever()
```

WebsocketServer lib used: https://github.com/Pithikos/python-websocket-server

Anyone knows what's the problem here?

**EDIT:**

Just found this page on git hub:

https://github.com/Pithikos/python-websocket-server/issues/19

It appears to be the lib issue and some of the users has posted the solution:

```
bytes([i^masks[idx % 4] for idx, i in enumerate(self.read_bytes(payload_length))]).decode()
```

However, I've absolutely no idea where to put this code.

Much appreciate help.

Answer (score 1):

In the WebsocketServer library code this:

```
decoded = ""
    for char in self.read_bytes(payload_length):
        char ^= masks[len(decoded) % 4]
        decoded += chr(char)
```

should be replaced with:

```
decoded=bytes([i^masks[idx % 4] for idx, i in enumerate(self.read_bytes(payload_length))]).decode()
```